# Bounded Operators without eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm looking for some interesting operators for which I can find invariant subspaces by hand. As most subspaces had some connections to eigenvectors, I'm currently searching for "non-trivial" / interesting (linear) bounded operators on Banach spaces, preferably Hilbert spaces, which do not have any eigenvalues.

I know about Volterra and multiplication operators but I can't seem to come up with any of my own.

In regards to Lomonosov's theorem, operators without eigenvalues, which commute with compact operators would be even better.

Comment: Convolution operators, i.e. the operators commuting with translations, on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ have no eigenvalues, as by the Fourier transform they are unitarily equivalent to multiplication operators.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I've found that the convolution is not closed on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118230/on-the-closedness-of-l2-under-convolution
Thus it wouldn't be a member of $B(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ (as it maps into a different space). Do you know of any other examples (or did I misunderstand) ?

Comment: What I meant was a bounded convolution operator. For example $L^1*L^2\subset L^2. $ More generally the convolution with a function $f$ is a bounded operator iff $\widehat{f}$ is bounded.

Comment: So something along the lines of:
Let $g\in L^1$ be given. Define $T_g:L^2\to L^2$ by the convolution ... where our $f\in L^2$ is being "convoluted" by $g$ ?

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: Ok, thank you !